# foundationdb running docker image macos database unavailable

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, foundationdb

I am trying to run foundation db using a docker image in Macos as below.

docker run --init --rm --name=fdb-0 foundationdb/foundationdb:6.2.22
Starting FDB server on 172.17.0.2:4500
This seems to start. But then I connect to fdb cli after logging into the container I get the following error statuses.
docker exec -it fdb-0 /bin/bash
root@9e8bb6985be5:/var/fdb# fdbcli
Using cluster file `/var/fdb/fdb.cluster'.

The database is unavailable; type `status' for more information.

Welcome to the fdbcli. For help, type `help'.
fdb> status

Using cluster file `/var/fdb/fdb.cluster'.

The coordinator(s) have no record of this database. Either the coordinator
addresses are incorrect, the coordination state on those machines is missing, or
no database has been created.

172.17.0.2:4500  (reachable)

Unable to locate the data distributor worker.

Unable to locate the ratekeeper worker.

I saw this issue https://forums.foundationdb.org/t/fdbcli-access-external-docker/1069. But, could not successfully run in host network as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try running fdbcli with `fdbcli --exec "configure new single memory ; status"`. This will start the new database with single redundancy memory mode.